# Retrofit returning empty arraylist but given valid POJO and Json to work with (tried other questions but the answers that worked on them don't on mne)

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

Does anyone here know how to use retrofit with a Django Rest Framework project? I have done everything I need to on both ends as documented and it returned valid Json that I generated Pojos with on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, but for some odd reason Retrofit keeps on returning an empty list from the Json results that ist's given I need this to be live so I demo my work to my supervisor tomorrow.. please help
P.S: Everything in the toast displays a 0 value, the size of the List that my storePlaces arraylist derives it's data from, the storePlaces Arraylist itself, and the status code returned by Retrofit.. hope that's usefull
Here is my code:

API endpoint:

```
// Request method and URL specified in the annotation
// Callback for the parsed response is the last parameter

@GET("/api/products/")
Call<List<Store>> getStoreList(@Query("format") String format);

@GET("/api/stores/{store_id}/")
Call<Store> getClickedStore(@Path("store_id") Integer store_id, @Query("format") String format);
```

POJO:

```
public class Store extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("picture")
@Expose
private String picture;
@SerializedName("Phone")
@Expose
private String Phone;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("website")
@Expose
private String website;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private String longitude;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private String latitude;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 *     The id
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 *     The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The picture
 */
public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

/**
 *
 * @param picture
 *     The picture
 */
public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The Phone
 */
public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

/**
 *
 * @param Phone
 *     The Phone
 */
public void setPhone(String Phone) {
    this.Phone = Phone;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/**
 *
 * @param email
 *     The email
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The website
 */
public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

/**
 *
 * @param website
 *     The website
 */
public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The longitude
 */
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @param longitude
 *     The longitude
 */
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The latitude
 */
public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @param latitude
 *     The latitude
 */
public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 *     The address
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

/**
 *
 * @param address
 *     The address
 */
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

the method calling Retrofit:

```
private ArrayList<Store> getDataSet() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofitClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    // create a new service call variable from the interface with retrofitClient
    ShoplistApiEndpointInterface apiService = retrofitClient.create(ShoplistApiEndpointInterface.class);

    //create a new APICall variable of the api interface with its type being that of the call method you'll invoke from the interface
    Call<List<Store>> storeListCall = apiService.getStoreList(FORMAT_SPECIFIER);

    // make the call asynchronously by calling enqueue on the Call type
    //FIXME: chane serverside encoding is option 1 (type:app/json, encoding: utf8)
    storeListCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Store>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Store>> call, Response<List<Store>> response) {
            // get status code from the HTTP response code
            statusCode = response.code();
            // add the parsed response body data (parsed pojo object list in this case)
            // to the arrayList with the addAll(Collection<type>) method
            List<Store> results = response.body();
            ressize = response.body().size();
            int initialSize = storePlaces.size();
            storePlaces.addAll(initialSize, results);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Store>> call, Throwable t) {
            // log the error here
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to download Place list", t);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.failed_to_download_list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Success, new data set is of size " + storePlaces.size() + " with status code: " + statusCode + " from source sized: " + ressize);

    return storePlaces;
}
```

the JSON (I've since updated it to restrict users from having more than readonly access to objects they didn't create, so the owner part is a new thing.. but JSONview extension for chrome validated both the first and this version of the JSON)

```
   [
{
id: 1,
name: "Shoprite Zm",
picture: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/productphotos/stores/serializer_snPGr8P.PNG",
Phone: "0255447854",
email: "fabf@ducj.omf",
website: "http://www.f.rd",
latitude: "0.000000",
longitude: "0.000000",
address: "noiibuiuwefd",
owner: 1
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Game fr",
picture: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/productphotos/stores/orcl.PNG",
Phone: "467565",
email: "fnini@irni.nur",
website: "http://afninni.gg.rtd",
latitude: "0.000000",
longitude: "0.000000",
address: "horvsawhgfl,md boisdrl",
owner: 1
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Ret",
picture: null,
Phone: "ajiwenpgoernen",
email: "fihIANPI@FNIIW.VID",
website: "http://FWIHFIFNVOI.fnawifni.afvn9weo.FNWIA",
latitude: "0.000000",
longitude: "0.000000",
address: "fawzsuvba.wfQSFBON",
owner: 1
}
]
```

(last few requests on the console output of the dev server for Django are for my app, the rest are from the browser)

[image: Image showing that both my browser and app successfully connected]

Comment: what is this `Call` class in `Call<List<Store>>`? why don't you use `List<Store>` directly as return type? specially you are defining the callback as `List<Store>` here `...new Callback<List<Store>>()...` also if you can post sample of returned JSON, it could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the result of an asynchronous callback from a method.  Your `storePlaces` is always going to be empty when the method returns it because the Retrofit http call won't have completed yet.

The way around this is to pass in your own callback method as a parameter of `getDataSet()` method.  Firstly define a generic callback interface:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void next(T result);
}
```

Then change your `getDataSet()` method:

```
public void getDataSet(Callback<List<Store>> callback) {

    //...

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Store>> call, Response<List<Store>> response) {

        // get status code from the HTTP response code
        statusCode = response.code();
        // add the parsed response body data (parsed pojo object list in this case)
        // to the arrayList with the addAll(Collection<type>) method
        List<Store> results = response.body();
        ressize = response.body().size();
        int initialSize = storePlaces.size();
        storePlaces.addAll(initialSize, results);

        callback.next(storePlaces);
    }

    //...
}
```

Now in your code where you use the `getDataSet` method you would call it like:

```
getDataSet(new Callback<List<Store>>() {
        @Override
        public void next(List<Store> results) {
            // use the results
        }
    }
)
```

**EDIT** Brief Explanation

This is an example of the *Observer Pattern*.

You register an `Observer` (a concrete implementation of the Callback interface) with your `Subject` (your Retrofit running method).  When the `Subject` has finished doing whatever task it does it notifies the `Observer` which then runs its code.

You can use this pattern in situations where there are async operations happening which you need to get a result from.  It is also used all over the Android framework for registering listeners such as OnClickListener.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code worked like a charm.. now I just have to iron out a few of my bugs (NPE in onBindViewHolder within my adapter). Could you please take the time to explain to me how you did this? I want to use this style on my realms for my offline data fetching too, and maybe even do it in different cntexts in future

Comment: I've added a brief explanation of the code.  Hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: It does actually, especially when you likened it to the way onClick functions